# Line of code appearing at the top of my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I am having a string of code appear on the top of my website and i have no idea why it is appearing.

[wordpresserror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtbTf.png)

Comment: Try disabling each plugin to check if one is causing this error. Something is malforming that tag.

Comment: need more info than a screenshot...

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your theme, a plugin, or customizations there's some code that should read something like this:

```html
<div class="home blog logged-in admin-bar etc" >
```

but actually reads something like this

```html
<div>class="home blog logged-in admin-bar etc"
```

with the `class` declaration lying outside the `<...>` characters that represent the beginning and end of the tag.